# yticklabels and ytick wont work

Tags: tikz-pgf, labels, ticks

I am plotting a graph using TikZ, but the yticks and yticklabels wont be set correctly.

This is the code that I use:

```
\documentclass[dvipsnames]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\pagestyle{empty}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.10}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{scope}[shift={(10cm,0cm)}]
\begin{axis}[
       xlabel= some label,
       ylabel= another label,
       grid=both,
       xmin=0,
       xmax=160,
       title = some measurement,
       height=5cm,
       width=8.05cm,
       ytick={0,0.5,1},
       yticklabels={0,0.5,1}]
\addplot [only marks, RoyalBlue] table [y=yy, x=xx ]{some_data.txt};
\addplot [RedOrange] table [y=yy, x=xx ]{more_data.txt};
\end{axis}
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

But this is the plot that I obtain:[image: Plot]

So why do the labels and ticks not work?

Comment: Without `some_data.txt` it's hard to test the code, but the `ytick` and `yticklabels` both work. What you are looking for is `ymin=0`. The `ytick` tells *where* the ticks should be, and the `yticklabels` tell *what* should be at the `ytick`s. Neither of them tell the axis from where to start or where to end.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

#### TL;DR:

You have to set the axis limits with `ymin=0` to make the `0` appear because PGFPlots adjusts the limits automatically and it doesn't know that the `0` *should* appear.

### Slightly wordier version (with pictures!):

I noticed that there is a general confusion regarding basic axis configuration among new PGFPlots users, so I'll write something to use for future reference. For experienced users this post will be, as the saying goes, "Raining on the wet".

Here I'll say everything in respect to the `y` axis because OP's question was regarding this specific axis, but they are all applicable to the `x` axis as well.

There are three things to configure in an axis:

- The limits with `ymin` and `ymax`;
- The ticks with `ytick`;
- The tick labels with `yticklabels`.

To illustrate what these properties do to the axes, I'll make OP's plot look like this:

[image: final]

### The axis limits with `ymin` and `ymax`

The first thing to set is the limits of the axes, that is, **from where to where** the axis goes. Think of the graph as a landscape, the limits are the size of the window, you'll see the ground, the sky, or both, depending only on the axis limits.

When you "just plot" something PGFPlots does you the favour to automatically get the maxima and minima of your data and use it as the axis limits (plus a little bit to make the view more comfortable).

But, as Don Knuth said, "computers don't understand things the way people do", and the automatic limits may not be the optimal ones. As in OP's case, the `0` was omitted, but the data went really close to it, so it would be nice to show the `0` anyway.

In PGFPlots the axis limits are set by the keys `ymin` and `ymax`. These values are from where to where the `y` axis of your plot should go. The following picture illustrates a change in the values of `ymin` and `ymax`:

[image: limits]

The graph on the left has `ymin = 0`, and the one on the right has `ymin = 0, ymax = 3.1416`. Because we didn't change the size of the graph, everything was shrinked to make it fit in the given limits.

### The axis ticks with `ytick`

But now there is that big white gap and no axis marks to aid the data visualization. The only marks I have in my axis are `0`, `0.5`, and `1`, and they are here because the original code had `ytick={0,0.5,1}`.

The axis ticks say the **Position** on the axis where it should be marked with a tick, so in the picture above my `y` axis is marked where the data is `0`, `0.5`, and `1`.

Now, let's say I want to mark the zero, the average and the maximum value of the data, and `\pi`, because of reasons, then I could use `ytick={0,0.7782,1.0640,3.1416}` (supposing I already know the average and the maximum):

[image: ticks]

But "hey", you ask, "what is going on here? Why are the values on the axis wrong? And where is the fourth mark that corresponds to `\pi`?" Well Jimmy, remember I said the ticks are the POSITION<sup>1</sup> of the marks. The first mark is at the zero, the second is about halfway between `0.5` and `1` (compare to the graph on the left), and the third is in the center of the highest blue dot, the maximum. The *labels* (the text to the left of the axis) are wrong because in the original code we have `yticklabels={0,0.5,1}`, and this is exactly what we're seeing. We'll get to the labels soon enough.

The `ytick`s must be always in "data units", so that PGFPlots knows where to put the ticks. To make things easier for larger plots you could use, for example, `ytick={0,0.5,...,10}` to make tick marks from zero to 10 with step of 0.5. Or, of course, you can let PGFPlots decide what it thinks it's best.

### The tick labels with `yticklabels`

Finally, the only thing to set is the tick labels (not to be confused with the axes labels!). The tick labels are **what goes on the ticks** of the axis. The tick labels can be anything, not only numbers. For example you could make the wish of your high school chemistry teacher (we all had that one) come true and add `yticklabels={potatoes,bananas,pineapple pizza}` and tell him that you finally compared two unrelated things. Tip: don't do this.

In our example, we can mark the axis with `yticklabels={zero,avg.,max.,$\pi$}`. Notice that now we have 4 values for the tick labels, not only three. This will complete the last label that was missing on the previous plot:

[image: ticklabels]

The `yticklabels` also accept a data range, as the `ytick`s: `yticklabels={0,0.5,...,10}`. But, in this specific case you could simply omit this key and PGFPlots would set the tick labels equal the ticks themselves.

---

I hope this post helped clarify the difference between these three axis settings. If I let something out, just ping me in the comments that I'll try to clarify it.

---

<sup>1</sup> [He took the time to press the shift key, Marge. I think he knows what he's talking about.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YtBY3.jpg)

---

Code for the final graph:

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{some_data_people_should_always_provide_when_posting_a_MWE.txt}
xx    yy
10.0  0.1336
15.0  0.1490
20.0  0.3718
25.0  0.3950
30.0  0.5325
35.0  0.6507
40.0  0.5285
45.0  0.7688
50.0  0.8695
55.0  0.7280
60.0  0.8209
65.0  0.7453
70.0  0.8983
75.0  0.8479
80.0  0.9079
85.0  0.8749
90.0  1.0454
95.0  0.8031
100.0 0.9619
105.0 0.8068
110.0 0.9424
115.0 0.8823
120.0 0.8997
125.0 0.9403
130.0 0.8937
135.0 0.9072
140.0 1.0448
145.0 0.9304
150.0 1.0001
155.0 1.0640
\end{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{more_data.txt}
xx yy
10.14705 0.2296
13.52941 0.2939
17.05882 0.3523
21.76470 0.4282
25.88235 0.4866
31.61764 0.5568
36.47058 0.6074
41.76470 0.6580
47.05882 0.7009
53.08823 0.7438
59.11764 0.7828
67.64705 0.8257
77.05882 0.8628
82.79411 0.8823
90.14705 0.9038
99.70588 0.9253
107.9411 0.9390
118.9705 0.9547
126.4705 0.9645
136.1764 0.9724
145.8823 0.9803
154.7058 0.9843
\end{filecontents}
\documentclass[dvipsnames]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\pagestyle{empty}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.10}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{scope}[shift={(10cm,0cm)}]
    \begin{axis}[
           xlabel=some label,
           ylabel=another label,
           grid=both,
           xmin=0,
           xmax=160,
           title=some measurement,
           height=5cm,
           width=8.05cm,
           ymin=0,
           ymax=3.1416,
           ytick={0,0.7782,1.0640,3.1416},
           yticklabels={zero,avg.,max.,$\pi$}]% ← Added this here
    \addplot [only marks, RoyalBlue] table [y=yy, x=xx ]{some_data_people_should_always_provide_when_posting_a_MWE.txt};
    \addplot [RedOrange] table [y=yy, x=xx ]{more_data.txt};
    \end{axis}
  \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```