# Change the names on the y-axis?

Tags: pgfplots, graphs

How do you change the names on the y-axis?
Instead of numbers on the y-axis like 1,2,3,4,5, I want f1,f2,f3,f4,f5 (text).
Thanks!

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}
    [
    ,width=13cm
    ,xlabel=Test
    ,ylabel=test
    ,xtick=data,
    %,ytick={0,1,...,5}
    ,yticklabels={f1,f2,f3,f4,f5}
    ]
    ytick={1,2,3,4,5},
    xmin=0, xmax=5,
    ymin=0, ymax=5,
    \addplot+[sharp plot] coordinates
    {(1,1) (2,2) (3,3) (4,4) (5,5)};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Comment: welcome to tex.se! please, help us to help you. extend your code sniped to complete but small document which we can copy and compile in our computers ...

Comment: Try using `,ytick={1,...,5}`.

Comment: try `xtick={0,1,...,5},
    ytick={0,1,...,5},
    yticklabels={,f1,f2,f3,f4,f5}`

Comment: The number of labels should match the number of ticks

Comment: This answer might help you setting axes: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/431714/134574

Comment: This is most likely due to the misplaced closing bracket of the optional arguments of the `axis` environment (`]`) which should be moved before `\addplot`. In addition you then have to either add a comma at the end of the `yticklabels` line or at the beginning of the (not commented) `ytick` line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a way to do it,

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}
    [width=13cm,
    xlabel=Test,
    ylabel=Test,
    xtick=data,
    ytick={1,2,3,4,5},  % specify where the yticks are located
    yticklabels={$f1$,$f2$,$f3$,$f4$,$f5$}, % specify corresponding tick labels
    xmin=0,
    xmax=5,
    ymin=0,
    ymax=5]
    \addplot+[sharp plot] coordinates {(1,1) (2,2) (3,3) (4,4) (5,5)};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture} 

\end{document}
```

[image]

You specify where you want the ticks, and then you specify what custom label should appear.

Hope that helps.

Romain